How to quickly find the largest files/dirs that differ between two directories that should be identical on Linux?
I'm trying to synchronize two hard drives. I thought most people who don't want to lose any data and don't use RAID would use such a method so that there would be a well-working GUI. That doesn't seem to be the case and on Linux I only found the Grsync GUI that can do that but since it can't copy over root-owned files, I still had to run this rsync command in the console:
sudo rsync -r -t -p -o -g --delete -l -s /media/veracrypt1 /media/veracrypt2
It basically means copy over everything as it is on the original drive and delete files ion the target drive that have been deleted on the source drive. I intend to clone the drive so its contents are 100% exactly identical and some parameters may still be missing in the command. Both ext4 drives are fully encrypted with VeraCrypt and are of the exact same model (also same storage size). I'm using Debian12/KDE.
My problem is that it always aborts before it has finished copying because the target drive is full, rsync shows this error:
rsync: [receiver] write failed on "/media/veracrypt2/file": No space left on device (28)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(380) [receiver=3.2.7]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)

But it shouldn't be full because lsblk -f shows that the source drive is below 95% FSUSE% with lots of GBs free.
I already tried deleting large files on the target disk and rerunning it with --exclude-from='./exclude-file.txt' --delete-excluded added to exclude a few large files and var/spool/ and var/cache/ which are somewhere in a directory of a system partition backup made with BackInTime. I also changed the root reserved disk space from 5% to 1% with sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/mapper/veracrypt2 which previously caused it to show 0B available even after deleting large files. It still doesn't run through.
How can I quickly find out which directories differ in size so that I can try to find the cause of this problem?
At the disk space not freed up problem a user suggested running commands like sudo du -sk /media/veracrypt2/*/* > ./before_deleting_files.txt to compare the disk space but it just shows 4for some files and directories and it takes long to load for each command.
I'm looking for a way that doesn't take very long for scanning, doesn't have other issues one must first solve, and ideally is either 1) something graphical dynamical like Graphical Disk Map (gdmap) where one can see (in this case also compare) the size visually and dynamically navigate around or 2) something that creates a report that simply lists which directories differ.

If the devices are meant to be identical twins  ... why don't you just do a dd if=/dev/disk/<one> of=/dev/disk/<two> bs=<your block-size> for the initial sync? Not  that I know anything about VeraCrypt...

I'd like to use a GUI eventually and there's a GUI (or a few) for rsync. Don't know what the advantage of using dd instead of rsync would be, I'll look into this but it should also work with rsync and this question is about how to find the difference which maybe is easy to do. I'm trying diff -qr /media/veracrypt1 /media/veracrypt2 but it's not useful to see which the problem files/dirs are because it just shows a lot of things missing on the target disk since it runs full before completion and all files not just the largest ones...and it takes long to run.

Biggest advantage: speed. No diffs, no comparisons, no compression on the line  ... obviously only for the initial run.

You could redirect the output of tree -d --du disk1 and tree -d --du disk2 to a file each and then diff them ...
To avoid the discrepancies from rsync:
In my comment above I got so completely hung up on the overall complexity of the system you described that I didn't even look closely at your rsync invocation.
That needs to be
sudo rsync -r -t -p -o -g --delete -l -s /media/veracrypt1/ /media/veracrypt2

Not
sudo rsync -r -t -p -o -g --delete -l -s /media/veracrypt1 /media/veracrypt2

Note the trailing slash on /media/veracrypt1/.

You may also shorten the list of options given to rsync by using -a (or --archive). Using -a is the same as -rlptgoD.

It is not the same as it differs from the above command by the -D flag (--archive is -rlptgoD). It also transfers "character and block device files". I'm intentionally using the command generated by Grsync and eventually only want to use a GUI that everybody can easily use. You didn't explain what the extra slash changes. It did what I thought it would: not create a subfolder. Grsync also needs a change that adds this slash to its command. The diff cmd shows lots of files from root partition backups are missing. For now I rerun the rsync after moving the folders out of subfolder.

@tink So I deleted a lot (like 20% of disk), then ran the rsync command with the slash again. It failed because it ran full again. I tried to see the difference between the two directories by comparing the two txt files generated by the sudo tree cmds with the Meld GUI. However, so much is different that it's hard to spot the issue. One can't see the biggest files in specific, 4096next to many files, and many files even differ in size such as Sdk/platforms/android-29/data/res//drawable-hdpi (I wasn't using that, maybe it just mismatched two different backups with most things unchanged).

@mYnDstrEAm hard to say whether the 20% were in the right place. I'd start from scratch if I were you.  If that's really not an option a more time-consuming find per disk find /media/veracrypt1 -type f -exec stat --printf "%N\t%s\n" "{}" > vol1 and find /media/veracrypt2 -type f -exec stat --printf "%N\t%s\n" "{}" > vol2 and then sdiff -s <(sort <vol1) <(sort <vol2) should show you differences.  There's a good chance that the first attempt left behind a directory /media/veracrypt2/veracrypt1 ... but we're now down to guessing.

Yes the first command created a subfolder as mentioned in the 2nd comment but I moved the folders to the directory above with sudo mv before running the next rsync run. I don't know why it's such a problem to just sync a directory with rsync, thought many would use it so all the problems I had with this simple use case have long been solved. The dirs it does copy are fine so sth is off and it could happen again even if I run it all over again. I'd like to run the rsync commands regularly to keep the drives in sync. Also find: missing argument to '-exec'

Not getting my paws on the machine I don't really know what else to suggest @mYnDstrEAm .. one last desperate guess: you have a bunch of hard-links on the source drive that don't translate to hard-links but actual files on the target. I'm using the rsync method myself to keep two encrypted external disks in sync, and it works a treat (me using encfs being the only difference). And unless there are no files at all the missing argument makes little sense.

It's been helpful. I tried running it with the -c after deleting a few backup dirs in case it didn't get some similar files/dirs were different but the disk got full again. I think the problem comes from BackInTime or Vorta backups that write to the source disk during the sync, I quit these backup apps and try again and am using the -H option, maybe that could be the solution if it's a hard link problem(?) I think the missing argument thing is just a small problem with the command syntax.

@tink It went through with the -H flag, I think that's what makes the syncing work. In addition to the few skipping non-regular file messages that showed in earlier runs and which I subsequently included in the --exclude-from= file, it also showed several messages of skipping non-regular file ".../docker/docker/overlay2/..." and skipping non-regular file "timeshift/snapshots/.../var/spool/..." but I don't think that's what caused this. It's solved for now but a more convenient way to quickly check if two dirs are in sync are still needed. I'll try the two tree commands to check later

@mYnDstrEAm - pleased to hear you're making progress.
